# Proving that a $\mathbb{Z}[i]$-module is free

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

I have the $\mathbb{Z}[i]$-module $$A=\{(z,w)\in\mathbb{Z}[i]^2:z+(1+i)w=0\bmod(2+2i)\}.$$

> I want to prove that it is free.

I know that being free means that $A$ is generated by a linearly independent subset $S\subset A$. The problem is that I don't know how to prove that. Should I search for all elements $s$ such that $a=\sum rs$ for $a\in A$ and $r\in \mathbb{Z}[i]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $z=-(1+i)w+2(1+i)y$, so the elements of $A$ have the form $$(-(1+i)w+2(1+i)y,w)=y(2(1+i),0)+w(-(1+i),1),$$ hence $A=\langle(2(1+i),0);(-(1+i),1)\rangle$. Now check that this is a basis for $A$.